# Amount of current after DC/DC conversion for PC/104

Tags: power-supply, embedded

Let say I have a AC to DC adapter with output 19V 7.9A connected to a 150W DC to DC power supply board (PC/104) with input 14-30V and output 5V.

What is amount of current I'll get from the 5V output board? Is it 150W/5V = 30A or 7.9A?

Sorry if this is so primitive question but I can't find corresponding reference.

Comment: What is PC/104?

Comment: @jippie it's a form factor for embedded modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll probably be more on the order of 135W out, or 27A @ 5V, since the first supply is only capable of 150W, and the DC-to-DC converter's efficiency is going to be on the order of 90%.

Answer (score 1):

The AC/DC and DC/DC will only draw what current they need.
Take the current for the PC/104 board, call it x.
x × 5 V is its power.
Divide by 90% (as Dave Tweed said) to get input power to the input power to the DC/DC.